# Activate tabber when navigation is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

ok so my website has a navigation with an id `#nav` so I want to activate a tabber based on the click navigation list. The navigation `#nav` has an html like this:-

```
 <ul id ="nav">
    <li><a href="tab1">Fred</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab2">Thom</a></li>
    <li><a href="tab3">Kay</a></li>
</ul>
```

now when Fred is clicked from the navigation, I want to activate this on the tabber which has an html like this

```
 <ul class="tabs">                                        
         <li><a href="#tab1">Fred</a></li>                                      
         <li><a href="#tab2">Thom</a></li>    
         <li><a href="#tab3">Kay</a></li>       
</ul>
```

and tab content like this:-

```
<div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Lorem</div>
<div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Ipsum</div>
<div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Dolor</div>
```

so I wrote the following line of jquery

```
$("#nav li").click(function() {

         var hash = location.hash;
          var sel = $("ul.tabs li a[href='" + hash + "'], ul#tabs li a[href='" + hash + "']");

    if (sel.length) { 

        sel.addClass("active").parent().addClass("active"); //Activate tab



        $(hash).show();
    }
```

but it's not working :( what am I doing wrong guys?

Comment: Is this a typo here? Or in your code too?  `<li><a href="#tab3"Kay</a></li>`  Also "its not working" is not a problem description.  What is happening/not happening?  Are there error messages?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do

Comment: when `Fred` is clicked, you want to show the div `tab1` right

Comment: exactly bro, and activate tab1. Just like how a normal tabber works but this time you can also activate and change the tabs based on the nav list clicked

Comment: which is the `tab` plugin used? is it jquery ui

Comment: it's not a tab plugin. It's basically my own jquery tabber I wrote for educational purposes and I want to add this feature to it

Comment: It's not a good idea to reject an edit fixing your horrible indentation. Your chance of getting good answers are equal to the quality of your question. Learn more about [editing in the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){

  $("#nav li").click(function(event) {
    var hash = $('a', this).attr('href');
    var sel = $("ul.tabs li a[href='#" + hash + "']");
    sel.trigger('click')
    return false;
  });

  $('.tab_content').hide();
  var tabllis = $('ul.tabs li');
  tabllis.click(function(){
    var $this = $(this).addClass('active');
    var hash = $('a', this).attr('href');

    tabllis.not($this).removeClass('active');

    $('.tab_content').hide();
    $(hash).show();

    return false;
  });

});
```

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/z66XzJWvp527LQQtl2WF?p=preview)

Comment: and that is just the same problem I'm having.It should be like a normal tabber such that when you click on 1, the other dissapears so that only 1 is being shown at any point in time and upon click and not just adding content like from your demo